Puppeteer: Failed to launch browser! chrome_crashpad_handler: --database is required
I was running a job in an Alpine image on Kubernetes, which is a c# program which uses the Puppeteer library, and I'm encountering the following error when trying to launch the browser:

Failed to launch browser! chrome_crashpad_handler: --database is
required

This is working during debugging and also when pulling the image from the registry and executing in a local docker.

my Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-alpine
code
RUN apk upgrade \
&& apk add --no-cache icu-libs icu-data-full chromium font-liberation \
&& apk del apk-tools \
 && fc-cache -f
ENV \
DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false \
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production \
 ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS= \
 CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser \
USER $APP_UID
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "<*.dll>"]
COPY . .

Please [edit] that into the post. Node canonical which might help: Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer

Opera 89 uses chrome_crashpad_handler.

Notably, other ones as an app are in OS which it is for among others, and in U4. And in Sublime Text 3 build 4180.

Puppeteer uses a browser to execute the document. To achieve this, start the browser within your Docker container. If you used a Linux or Ubuntu image, execute the following command to install the browser:
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser


I have this statement in Dockerfile
RUN apk upgrade \  && apk add --no-cache icu-libs icu-data-full chromium font-liberation \  && apk del apk-tools \  && fc-cache -f
@jignesh-patel Do I need to replace chromium with chromium-browser or add it as a new dependency?

it is not available in 8.0-alpine

You can use any browser, whichever supports it, but you must have a browser.
You have to pass the below argument while you are launching the puppeteer.
Refernace for Nodejs:
<<<
await puppeteer.launch({
executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
args: ['--disable-gpu', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--no-sandbox', '--no-zygote']
});





